# using Ajax in wordpress and receive this error message "NetworkError: 404 Not Found"

Tags: wordpress

I am using Ajax in Wordpress and receive this error message "NetworkError: 404 Not Found".
And I have no clue what is going wrong.

EDIT: This is my link: http://www.myfavouritelink.nl/?page=bookmark#

More details: via Firebug console, I could see the correct response. However I still receive this error ""NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.myfavouritelink.nl/wp-content/themes/arthemia/js/ajax/getBookmark.php?id=54&action=edit""

Comment: Can you post a link to the site?

Comment: @Jeremy Jared See the link above

Comment: The link you posted is returning a 404 header. You'll need to look into getBookmark.php to find out why

Comment: @Pekka The response fron getBookmark.php is fine. I don't know why the return data does not update into to defined elementId. The following is my ajax call `code`  $.ajax({
 url: "/wp-content/themes/arthemia/js/ajax/getBookmark.php",
 dataType: "html",
 context: document.body,
 data: "id="+rowid+"&action="+action,
 success: function(data){
     $("#row_"+rowid).html(data);
 }
 ,
 error: function(data) {
     alert(data);
 }
    });

Comment: @ruka are you getting an alert with the "NetworkError" error message? If you are, you are getting a 404 header along with your response, leading to the `error` callback being triggered. You will need to look into your PHP script to find out why that happens.

Comment: @Pekka The alert is [Object Object] and the error message "NetworkError: 404 Not Found" is from Firebug

Comment: Your script is returning a 404 header. You'll need to look into getBookmark.php to find out why

Comment: @Pekka The following is the response from getBookmark, That means the getBookmark is doing well. 'code' <form name='frm_edit' method='post' action='?action=save'></td><td><input type='text' name='favor_name' id='name' value ='afternoon tea' class='edit_input' /></td><td><input type='text' name='favor_link' id='link' value ='http://www.kunstenaarswinkel.com/afternoon-tea.html' class='edit_input' /></td><td><input type='text' name='favor_tag' id='tag' value ='afternoon tea' class='edit_input' /></td><td> </form> 'code'

Comment: A script can send a fully valid HTML body *and* a 404 header at the same time.

Comment: @Pekka I am lost now. I am using wordpress and there are so many files. this is the include file "require('../../../../wp-blog-header.php');" :(

Answer (score 1):

**Try changing this line:**

```
url: "/wp-content/themes/arthemia/js/ajax/getBookmark.php"
```

**to this:**

```
url : "bloginfo('wpurl')/wp-content/themes/arthemia/js/ajax/getBookmark.php",
```

Comment: Hey, I found out the problem. In my getBookmark I had an html error. I comment the echo "<form ...>" and did not comment the close form tag. This is a very stupid mistake from me. Thanks both of you!